# How to write regular expression that accept single and double quote?

Tags: asp.net

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^([a-zA-Z\s]{3,25})$");
```

This regular expression only accept character and spaces(length range between 3-25) but not accept single and double quate. so, How I have to modify this expression so that it would be accept single and double quote?

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't provide your non matching pattern I am just matching within the your given length. You can try it like,

```
  Regex regex = new Regex(@"^([a-zA-Z'""\s]{3,25})$");
```

[Here is working example](https://regex101.com/r/aI4rA5/2)